# Juniper Firewall - software that can report on traffic analysis?

Tags: juniper

I'd like to find some open source software (or relatively inexpensive) that can run analysis against the syslog messages of a Juniper SSG (netscreen OS) firewall and provide things like "Top destinations", "Top protocols", "Overall usage"...

Anyone know of such a tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We decided to go with Manage Engine's firewall analyzer.  Cacti is too difficult to manage and maintain and Splunk wouldn't do what we were after.

Comment: I would hardly describe this software as inexpensive!

Comment: Depends on how you look at it.  We got a nice discount because of the industry we are in.  We were originally looking at stuff that was going to cost $15-25k.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/) for analyzing syslog files.

Answer (score 0):

[Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) is an open source graphing/alerting solution that, along with a Syslog server like syslog-NG (open source as well) and the [Syslog](http://cactiusers.org/wiki/HaloeDocs) plugin, should get you what you need.  Cacti's great, haven't tried that plugin though, but it's on my (long) todo list of software to evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want a commercial solution? I wrote a small Perl script that can do the same. See if it is useful:

```
use strict;

my $log = shift;
my $n = shift || 5;

open FILE, $log or die "Can't open the file";

my %connections;
my %all_connections;

while (<FILE>){
    if (/^.*sent=(\d+) rcvd=(\d+) src=([\S+]+) dst=([\S+]+) src_port=(\d+) dst_port=(\d+).*$/){
        my ($src_ip, $dst_ip, $dst_port, $bytes) = ($3,$4, $6, $2);
        my $src_port = "";
        my ($src_int, $dst_int) = ("DMZ","TRUST");
        # Calculating Top users based on connection counts
        $connections{$src_int." => ".$dst_int}{conn_count}{$src_ip." => ".$dst_ip}++;
        $connections{$src_int." => ".$dst_int}{src_count}{$src_ip}++;
        $connections{$src_int." => ".$dst_int}{dst_count}{$dst_ip}++;

        # Calculating Top users based on bytes transferred
        $connections{$src_int." => ".$dst_int}{conn_bytes}{$src_ip." => ".$dst_ip} += $bytes;
        $connections{$src_int." => ".$dst_int}{src_bytes}{$src_ip}+= $bytes;
        $connections{$src_int." => ".$dst_int}{dst_bytes}{$dst_ip}+= $bytes;

        $all_connections{sprintf ("%-36s => %-36s (%-6d) %12s",$src_ip, $dst_ip, $dst_port)} += $bytes;
    }

}


foreach my $connection (sort keys %connections){
    print "--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
    print "STATISTICS FOR CONNECTION ", $connection, "\n";
    print "--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";

    print "\nTop $n Connections by Bytes transferred\n";
    my $i = 0;
    printf ("%-56s %15s\n","Connection","Bytes Transferred");
    printf ("%-56s %15s\n","----------","-----------------");
    foreach my $conn_string (sort {$connections{$connection}{conn_bytes}{$b} <=> $connections{$connection}{conn_bytes}{$a} } keys %{$connections{$connection}{conn_bytes}}){
        last if $i > ($n-1);
        printf ("%-56s %15.0f\n", $conn_string, $connections{$connection}{conn_bytes}{$conn_string});
        $i++;
    }
    print "\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
    print "\nTop $n Source by Bytes transferred\n";
    my $i = 0;
    printf ("%-56s %15s\n","Source","Bytes Transferred");
    printf ("%-56s %15s\n","------","-----------------");
    foreach my $conn_string (sort {$connections{$connection}{src_bytes}{$b} <=> $connections{$connection}{src_bytes}{$a} } keys %{$connections{$connection}{src_bytes}}){
        last if $i > ($n-1);
        printf ("%-56s %15.0f\n", $conn_string, $connections{$connection}{src_bytes}{$conn_string});
        $i++;
    }

    print "\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
    print "\nTop $n Destination by Bytes transferred\n";
    my $i = 0;
    printf ("%-56s %15s\n","Destination","Bytes Transferred");
    printf ("%-56s %15s\n","-----------","-----------------");
    foreach my $conn_string (sort {$connections{$connection}{dst_bytes}{$b} <=> $connections{$connection}{dst_bytes}{$a} } keys %{$connections{$connection}{dst_bytes}}){
        last if $i > ($n-1);
        printf ("%-56s %15.0f\n", $conn_string, $connections{$connection}{dst_bytes}{$conn_string});
        $i++;
    }


    print "\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
    print "\nTop $n connections by Connection count\n";
    my $i = 0;
    printf ("%-56s %15s\n","Connection","Connection Count");
    printf ("%-56s %15s\n","----------","----------------");
    foreach my $conn_string (sort {$connections{$connection}{conn_count}{$b} <=> $connections{$connection}{conn_count}{$a} } keys %{$connections{$connection}{conn_count}}){
        last if $i > ($n-1);
        printf ("%-56s %15d\n", $conn_string, $connections{$connection}{conn_count}{$conn_string});
        $i++;
    }

    print "\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
    print "\nTop $n Source by Connection count\n";
    my $i = 0;
    printf ("%-56s %15s\n","Source","Connection Count");
    printf ("%-56s %15s\n","------","----------------");
    foreach my $conn_string (sort {$connections{$connection}{src_count}{$b} <=> $connections{$connection}{src_count}{$a} } keys %{$connections{$connection}{src_count}}){
        last if $i > ($n-1);
        printf ("%-56s %15d\n", $conn_string, $connections{$connection}{src_count}{$conn_string});
        $i++;
    }

    print "\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
    print "\nTop $n Destination by Connection count\n";
    my $i = 0;
    printf ("%-56s %15s\n","Destination","Connection Count");
    printf ("%-56s %15s\n","-----------","----------------");
    foreach my $conn_string (sort {$connections{$connection}{dst_count}{$b} <=> $connections{$connection}{dst_count}{$a} } keys %{$connections{$connection}{dst_count}}){
        last if $i > ($n-1);
        printf ("%-56s %15d\n", $conn_string, $connections{$connection}{dst_count}{$conn_string});
        $i++;
    }

    print "\n\n";


}

printf ("%-30s       %-36s  %-6s  %12s\n", "Source IP", "Destination IP", "Port", "Bytes");
printf ("%-30s       %-36s  %-6s  %12s\n", "-------------------------------", "------------------------------------", "------", "------------");
#map {print $_->[0]."\n"} @all_connections;

#print Dumper(\%all_connections);

foreach my $connection (sort {$all_connections{$b} <=> $all_connections{$a}} keys %all_connections)
{
    print "$connection  $all_connections{$connection}\n";
}

#map {printf ("%-36s (%-6d) => %-36s (%-6d) %12s\n", $_->[0], $_->[1], $_->[2], $_->[3], $_->[4])} sort {$b->[4] <=> $a->[4]} @all_connections;
```